# Subsurface modifier has no "render" option

Tags: rendering, interface, subdivision-surface

I have a subsurface modifier on the character that I am working on. But at some point the "render" option just got ...bugged? (And I don't know when or why this happened) It doesn't look right and does not work for rendering either.

[image]

I can however change it to a multiresolution modifier and subdivide + render it that way.

However I would rather know what's going on here before going forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable "Experimental" features (it looks like you have done that)

[image]

the subdivision modifier changes a bit and it allows "adaptive" subdivisions. You are not forced to use it though.

To *not* use the adaptive feature, just use the "*Levels:*" slider under it: it works exactly as the "*Render:*" slider works in the non-experimental version.

[image]

(you can switch back and forth, the value stays the same)

Comment: Yo dude. That was it. Thank you so much lol.  :D

Comment: Oh man I was so stupid. I got confused by the UI since i was expecting to choose the  "render value" where now just was a seemingly empty "render:      " . Didn't even realize the "Level Value" belonged to "render:  "  . I thought it belonged to "adaptive" . Like " adaptive level 2 " .....

Comment: @Shinsakuto it's not you: sometimes the interface looks confusing! It's normal to be a bit confused when the interface suddenly changes :)
Btw, I have removed your "PS" from the question as artistic feedback are not on-topic on this site. 
Familiarize yourself with the site and welcome to BSE! :)